# EDIT: how to pass ode parameters in second function-Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a dynamical system `ode`, which I need to solve for various values of one of its parameters, the parameter `r`. However, the function `sigm` (sigmoid function), appears many times in the system and it was considered preferable to code it as a separate function outside of the system.

```
r = 0:+0.01:1;
time = 0:.01:10;
y0 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]; 
y = NaN(length(time),length(y0),length(r));

for i=1:length(r)
    [t,y(:,:,i)] = ode45(@(t,y) ode(t,y,r(i)),time, y0);
    ...
end

function dydt = ode(~,y,r)

    dydt = NaN(8,1);

    dydt(1) = y(5);
    dydt(2) = y(6);
    dydt(3) = y(7);
    dydt(4) = y(8);
    dydt(5) = sigm(y(3)-y(4)) - y(5)- y(1);
    dydt(6) = sigm(y(3)-y(4)) - y(6) - y(2);
    dydt(7) = sigm(y(1)) - y(7) - y(3);
    dydt(8) = sigm(y(2)) - y(8) - y(4);
end

function X = sigm(u,r)
    X = 1/(1+exp(r*(6-u)));
end
```

The point where i am having a difficulty is that, the parameter `r`, only appears in the sigmoid function and not in the ode. Thus, when I am trying to solve the system for many values of this parameter, i get error `not enough input arguments`.

How can I pass this parameter into the second function?

A potential way, would be to put the whole `sigm` function, within the `ode` function:

```
function dydt = ode(~,y,r)

    dydt = NaN(8,1);

    dydt(1) = y(5);
    dydt(2) = y(6);
    dydt(3) = y(7);
    dydt(4) = y(8);
    dydt(5) = sigm(y(3)-y(4)) - y(5)- y(1);
    dydt(6) = sigm(y(3)-y(4)) - y(6) - y(2);
    dydt(7) = sigm(y(1)) - y(7) - y(3);
    dydt(8) = sigm(y(2)) - y(8) - y(4);

    function X = sigm(u)
            X = 1/(1+exp(r*(6-u)));
    end
end
```

, but I am guessing it is not a good coding tacticts

Comment: What is `r`? It has a length, so it is an array, it is a parameter, so it should be a scalar... Try to pass `@(t,y) ode(t,y,r(i))`.

Comment: exactly the same result

Comment: If you pass no arguments to `sigm()`, then of course it has `not enough input arguments`.

Comment: Sure I do. The arguments to `sigm()`, pass by the ode function. It's `sigm(u)`, where `u` is a certain calculation of the ode's input `y`.

Comment: The point is, no such computation is visible in the code you added up to now. And it should be `sigm(u,r)` to match the definition of the function.

Comment: I am afraid, I am not sure, what you mean. It is indeed `sigm(u,r)` as it appears above in the code. What am I supposed to add in the code to make the dependence or `r` visible in the ode?

Comment: Is the line `dydt(5,:) = sigm();` verbatim from your code or is it abbreviated? Why do you expect that the argument and return value of the ODE function are matrix valued? Where do you construct the return matrix `dydt`? Can you condense the code to a minimal working example (say state dimension 2) exhibiting the same error?

Comment: it was an abbreviation, but I can definitely do as you asked.

Comment: If it was not implicitly clear from my previous comments, after the first change the parts of the code that were shown, with sensible extrapolation of the missing parts, were correct, there was no place that error could have originated. That's why the guidelines ask for a MWE and (or at least) the main part of the error message.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I edited it

Comment: You are still missing to pass the parameter `r` in the `sigm` call.

Comment: yes, this is what I don't know how to do..

Comment: `dydt(5) = sigm(y(3)-y(4), r) - y(5)- y(1);` you do that like for any other function with multiple parameters.

Comment: thank you! this works!
Please post your last response as an answer so that I can accept it and close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the function declaration

```
function dydt = ode(~,y,r)
```

the parameter `r` is defined as a local variable that can then be used like any other scalar value, such as passing it as the second parameter to `sigm`, like in

```
dydt(5) = sigm(y(3)-y(4), r) - y(5)- y(1);
```